# How set start/end position ng2-nouislider?

Tags: angular

I have slider-scroll. I do not understand how to ask. Meanings. which will be on the chart but will not be active.
   The documentation is bad. There are properties of min max, but there is nothing in the similarity of min-start or min-limit ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIUpC.png)

In Html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form2">
      <nouislider [config]="someRangeconfig" [connect]="true" [(ngModel)]="someRange"  [formControl]="form2.controls.range"></nouislider>
    </form>
```

TS:

```
public someRange:number[] = [300, 3000];
  public form2:FormGroup;
  public someRangeconfig:any = {
    behaviour: 'drag',
    connect: true,
    //start:300,
    //margin: 5,
    step: 1,
    //limit: 1000,
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 5000
    }
  };

 public ngOnInit() {
    this.form2 = this.fb.group({'range': [[300, 3000]]});
  }
```

I use: https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider

Answer (score 1):

Check this working Code.

**HTML**'

```
<nouislider start="startingRange" [connect]="true" [min]="25000" [max]="800000" [step]="77500" tabindex="9" (ngModelChange)="onSliderChange($event)" name="slider"></nouislider>
<div class="top-section">
    <div>
        <span *ngIf="startingRange[0] == 25000">&lt;</span>{{startingRange[0] | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.0-0'}}</div>
    <div>{{startingRange[1] | currency:'USD':'symbol':'2.0-0'}}
        <span *ngIf="startingRange[1] == 800000">+</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

startingRange = [25000, 800000];

```
onSliderChange(event: any) {
    this.contactFiltersForm.value.incomeRange = event
    .toString()
    .replace(',', '-');
    this.selectedContactFilters.incomeRange = event
      .toString()
      .replace(',', '-');
  }
```